# Facebook posting gif issue

Tags: html, facebook, url, gif

I do have a problem while posting gif to facebook from my web app.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Gif</title>

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="322819664717135">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ADZZY">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.adzzy.net/c.gif">
<meta property="og:title" content="Sharing sample of Adzzy">
<meta property="og:description" content="sample description">

<meta property="og:type" content="video.other">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adzzy.net/c.gif">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="524">

<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.adzzy.net/Work/Gif/Y3w1MDB8NTI0">

</head>
```

Between head tags I have defined these properties and it returns :

```
File: http://www.adzzy.net/d.gif //filepath in myserver
Width: 500
Height: 524
url: http://www.adzzy.net/Work/Gif/YnwyMDB8MjU5 //url of the path
```

Now I copy and paste this url to facebook post to test the output and it shows:

[image]

This usually happens when a gif size is higher than kilobytes. When I try with smaller files it displays correctly.

As far as I observe from facebook when I inspect gif files it wraps under a div and show the mp4 extension of that gif file. But in my current situation it shows them as img files as it wraps under img tags.

I am very confused right now. What should I do for proper gif posting to facebook? Especially in large files i am always facing with this issue.. Any helps?

Comment: `og:url` needs to be the URL of the HTML document containing this meta data itself, not of the image. Right now, [the debug tool complains](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adzzy.net%2FWork%2FGif%2FY3w1MDB8NTI0) that your document does not contain any relevant OG meta data, and that is _because_ you are wrongfully sending it to the image URL to look for that data.

Comment: I've corrected the og:url parameter but right now the behaviour changes it did not preview it as gif file it shows something differenet when you look it to link preview, any ideas ? @CBroe

Comment: _“Provided og:image URL, `http://www.adzzy.net/c.gif` could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb.”_ – so you’ll need to see that you stay under that file size limit with your GIFs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that c.gif is under 8MB here this is the size of c.gif that has been directly taken from my server: 2,80 MB (2.945.024 bayt). Is this bug or something else cause I guess I am doing the same thing as giphy does (I also inspect their gifs and observe the tags) I couldnt get where the conflict occurs @CBroe

Comment: It might not only be the file size, but load time as well. In my browser it takes around 25 seconds til that GIF is done loading – and the FB scraper is not the most patient.

Comment: So in my actual question I told that 'This usually happens when a gif size is higher than kilobytes. When I try with smaller files it displays correctly.' so this could be related with load time as you said not only the file size. In giphy I generally observe og:url and og:image are the same and they both are .gif files but as your reference I've changed og:url to html document that contains metadata and that errors gone but still gif cannot be previewed in Facebook endpoint proberly. At last resort, do you have any other suggestions ? Thanks @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

You need to post GIF as video not in photos.